# Passing function returns as method parameters in Python

Tags: python, methods, parameters, iterable-unpacking

I'm currently writing a small code to move two balls around in a Tkinter GUI and do some other stuff too. 
I've already written a code that works, but as it uses a lot of global variables I tried to improve it. 
Below I've pasted the code section relative to my question :

can.coords needs five parameters : the object you wanna 'move', and the new coordinates.
The returns from both moveLeft() and addThirty() are two items lists. 
Of course, the star operator (to unpack a list) doesn't work .

How do I pass the four items from the two returned lists of the functions into the method .coords() ?

PS : I'm new to Python and even to programming.

```
def moveo (lr, tb):
    global newX, newY
    newX = x+lr
    newY = y+tb
    return newX, newY


def moveLeft ():
    coordins = moveo (-10, 0)
    return coordins

def addThirty (func):
    i = 0
    coordinsNew  = func
    coordinsNew = list(coordinsNew)
    while i < 2:
        coordinsNew[i] = coordinsNew[i]+30
        i += 1
    return coordinsNew

Button(wind, text = 'Left', command=can.coords (oval1,(*moveLeft()),(*addThirty(moveLeft()))))
```

Comment: As a side note: Even if you only have one iterable of args to unpack—or if a future version of Python allowed more than one (which has been suggested, and might happen if someone could work out all the edge cases… assuming there is a way they could be worked out…), you can't wrap the starred expression in parentheses. That forces it to be evaluated as a separate expression before you even get to the function call, which will raise something like `SyntaxError: can only use starred expression as assignment target` (slightly different in different Python versions).

Comment: Thank you for the note. I had that error earlier. 
However, now, both `*moveLeft() + *addThirty(moveLeft())` and `*(moveLeft()) + *(addThirty(moveLeft()))` raise an 'invalid syntax' error. Why is that ?

Comment: You can't have two starred expressions in the same call, period. Adding parentheses around the starred expressions just added a _second_ error on top of that; it doesn't fix it. (And adding parentheses around the part after the star does nothing at all.) Try out a trivial example, with only one starred expression, in the interactive interpreter, and you should get it pretty quickly.

Comment: Anyway, as I explained in my answer, solving this problem still won't make your code work; you've got a much more fundamental problem to solve: You're not passing a function to be called each time the button is clicked; you're calling the function now, and passing its return value to be called each time the button is clicked (which will ultimately probably give you some error about `NoneType` or `tuple` or some such thing not being callable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always combine two lists or two tuples into one just with `+`:

```
can.coords(oval1, *(moveLeft() + addThirty(moveLeft())))
```

Even if you've got sequences (or even iterators) of different types, you can always convert them:

```
can.coords(oval1, *(moveLeft() + tuple(addThirty(moveLeft())))))
```

However, you really should step back and ask why this needs to be one line in the first place. It scrolls off the right edge of the screen, it requires enough complex parenthesization that you have to think about it to understand it, etc. Why not just do this:

```
top, left = moveLeft()
bottom, right = addThirty(moveLeft())
can.coords(oval1, top, left, bottom, right)
```

---

In a comment, you say:

> I can't do this because I want the coordinates to change every time I press the button. So the button needs to : execute both functions to modify the coordinates and pass them to can.coords () in one time.

Just putting it in one line doesn't do that, or even help make that easier. The way you've written it, you're calling `can.coords` once, and passing the resulting return value as the command. That's not what you want. What you need to pass is a *function* that does all this stuff.

Which means that you *definitely* want to split it up into multiple lines. For example:

```
def update_coords():
    top, left = moveLeft()
    bottom, right = addThirty(moveLeft())
    can.coords(oval1, top, left, bottom, right)
Button(wind, text = 'Left', command=update_coords)
```

Because the only way to put it in one line would be with an equivalent `lambda` or `partial`, which will be even *more* unreadable than a call; something like:

```
Button(wind, text = 'Left', command=lambda: can.coords(oval1, *(moveLeft() + addThirty(moveLeft()))))
```

---

To explain the difference between passing a function, and calling a function and passing its return value, let's take a much simpler example:

```
>>> def foo():
...     return 2
>>> print(foo)
<function foo at 0x12345678>
>>> print(foo())
2
```

Here, it should be pretty clear what the difference is. `foo` is an expression whose value is the function `foo` itself. But `foo()` is an expression whose value is determined by calling `foo` with no arguments, then using whatever was returned (in this case, `2`).

If we make it a little more complicated, it's no different:

```
>>> def bar(x, y):
...     return x+y
>>> print(bar)
<function bar at 0x12345680>
>>> print(bar(2, 3))
6
```

So, it's obvious how you can pass around `bar` itself, or how you can pass the `6` you get back from `bar(2, 3)`… but what if you want to pass a function that can be called with no arguments and return the same thing that `bar(2, 3)` would return? Well, you don't have such a thing; you have to create it.

You can do this in two ways: creating a new function:

```
>>> def new_function():
...     return bar(2, 3)
```

… or partially evaluating the function:

```
>>> new_function = partial(bar, 2, 3)
```

Your case adds a few extra wrinkles: you're starting with a bound method rather than a function, you need to make sure the arguments get evaluated each time the new function is run (because calling `moveLeft()` twice each time rather than just once is every bit as important as calling `can.coords` each time), and you've got a bunch of arguments that you get in a complicated way. But none of those wrinkles make things any harder; you just have to look past them:

```
>>> def new_function():
...     can.coords(oval1, *(moveLeft() + addThirty(moveLeft())))
```

(The partial would be a lot harder to write, because you have to compose a sequence of functions together just to get the parameters, which you need to partial as well… but whenever partial isn't trivial in Python, don't try to figure it out, just write an explicit function.)

Comment: I can't do this because I want the coordinates to change every time I press the button. So the button needs to : execute both functions to modify the coordinates and pass them to can.coords () in one time.
I agree that the line is difficult to read, but I can't think of another way of writing it.

Comment: Ah… well, that's not what your code, or Viktor Kerkez's code, actually does. Putting it in one line won't help that. Let me edit the answer.

Comment: Yeah that must be the way of doing what I want in a proper way. Could you explain `The way you've written it, you're calling can.coords once, and passing the resulting return value as the command.` ? 
I don't get why the way I've written is doesn't give the same result.

Comment: @PierreOcinom: Let me edit the answer to try to explain further, instead of replying in a comment.

Comment: Thank you for the edits. I get it now. 
That means every time your command needs to call a function that works with parameters, you'll **always** have to write another function with empty parenthesis including the first function in order to be able to pass that function without the parenthesis to pass the first function and not its returned value. Am I right ?

Comment: @PierreOcinom: Yes. Well, 95%. You **always** have to **create** another function with no arguments, so you can pass that function. And the easiest way to do that is almost always to write that new function explicitly. It's not the only way (see `partial` again for an example)… but if it's the only way _you_ ever use, you'll be just fine.

Comment: I just found out something new, as I have posted in my answer below. What do you think of it ?

Answer (score 1):

If both functions return the same type (list or tuple) then just do:

```
can.coords(oval1, *(moveLeft() + addThirty(moveLeft())))
```

If they return different types (tuple, list, iterator, whatever) do:

```
args = list(moveLevt())
args.extend(addThirty(moveLeft()))
can.coords(oval1, *args)
```

Comment: In his example, neither function seems to return a list. Fortunately, they both return a tuple, so you can just concatenate them with `+`.

Comment: Also, why do the explicit `args = list(…)` and then `args.extend(b)` instead of just `list(a) + list(b)`?

Comment: Actually my code wasn't working because I had forgotten to convert the return from moveLeft() to a list. Of course, the way you have written the code with only one star to unpack is even better. Thanks.

Comment: @PierreOcinom: But you don't need to convert _either_ of them to a list, if they're both tuples (assuming you can be sure that's always true).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for digging up this topic, but after an interesting answer from a user on another topic, I thought I'll improve the answer to this question. Actually, you can assign a function with arguments to a command as long as it returns a function. In this case, it will avoid you a lot of trouble as you don't need to write a new function for every left right, down etc.

As you see, I can use arguments to the functions I assign to command:

```
command=move1(0,10)
```

I've written the code for only one oval, just to show how it works.

```
from tkinter import *

x1, y1 = 135, 135
x2, y2 = 170, 170



def move1 (x, y):
    def moveo1 ():
        global x1, y1
        x1, y1 = x1+x, y1+y
        can.coords (oval1, x1, y1, x1+30, y1+30)
    return moveo1



##########MAIN############

wind = Tk()
wind.title ("Move Da Ball")

can = Canvas (wind, width = 300, height = 300, bg = "light blue")
can.pack (side = LEFT,padx = 5, pady = 5)


oval1 = can.create_oval(x1,y1,x1+30,y1+30,width=2,fill='orange') #Planet 1
Button(wind, text = 'Left', command=move1(-10,0)).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Right', command=move1(10,0)).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Top', command=move1(0,-10)).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)
Button(wind, text = 'Bottom', command=move1(0,10)).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)


Button(wind, text = 'Quit', command=wind.destroy).pack(padx = 5, pady = 5)

wind.mainloop()
```

Comment: What you've done is to change `move1` into a function that returns a partially-evaluated version of the original function. This is similar to using `lambda x, y: move1(x, y)` or `partial(move1, x, y)` instead of just `move1(x, y)`, in that you get a new function each time, but it has the advantage of putting the extra verbosity in one place instead of four. I think the lambda is the most common/idiomatic version in tkinter code, but all three are reasonable.